# Failed to list all calendars with microsoft graph api

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm currently trying to deal with calendars using graph api.
Last week, I've tried to use

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user_id}/calendars
```

and

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user_id}/calendars?$top=500
```

to list the calendars from my_calendar groups.
However, only the calendars I've created months ago can be listed, and all the calendars I create today are not listed. (there are only 15 calendars)

Note. I've tried to use

1. UI: https://outlook.office.com/calendar/view/month
2. graph explorer sending api: post [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user_id}/calendars](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/%7Buser_id%7D/calendars)
   to create the calendar.
   However, all the new calendars I create can not be listed by the list calendars api.

Best regards,
Thank you in advance~!

Answer (score 1):

List calendars - Get all the user's calendars (/calendars navigation property), get the calendars from the default calendar group or from a specific calendar group.

For getting delegated shared calendars, use this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-get-shared-events-calendars).

Comment: Thank you, my problem is that for a certain user, I cannot list the newly created events using graph api. However, the older ones can be listed correctly.
For example:
1. I've created calendars a, b, and c in 2021/01, I can list them using graph api correctly.
2. If I create calendars d, e, and f now, still only calendars a, b, and c will be listed with graph api.

Comment: Had the same problem. The calendar appeared finally after I logged in to the mailbox with the Office365 web client, where I could see it. After this, the Graph API returned it, too.